# How to set up an arbitrary viewpoint in matplotlib's 3D axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, elevation, azimuth

I am trying to set an arbitrary viewpoint for an `Axes3D` object `ax` using

```
ax.view_init(azim=a, elev=e)
```

but this method does the elevation rotating the "z" axis with respect to a horizontal axis *co-planar to the screen*, rather than the axis "x" or "y". Since the azimuth parameter affects the direction of the x-y plane, it is not possible in this way to achieve an arbitrary orientation (e.g., "x" pointing out of the screen, "y" going upwards and "z" going from the left to the right of the screen).

Is there a way to set up an arbitrary viewpoint?

Comment: I find mpl 3D plotting to be way less than it should. I am curious to see answers to this question, but Python surely deserves some serious 3D Visualization tools (that are not a pain to get working).